# Modify data to reflect another record in same group

Tags: sql, oracle, view, toad

I have a view which produces data like so:

```
---ID-------StartDate---EndDate----Endpoint number-------             
G002S6YE    01/06/2011  31/05/2013  1012427316307
G002W1AY    27/06/2011  30/09/2012  1012427316307
```

`Endpoint number` is *usually* different for each record. In some cases however where it isn't (such as this example) I need to modify the `EndDate` of the earlier record to the day before the `StartDate` on the later record so in this example the data should show as:

```
---ID-------StartDate---EndDate----Endpoint number-------             
G002S6YE    01/06/2011  26/06/2011  1012427316307
G002W1AY    27/06/2011  30/09/2012  1012427316307
```

This is based purely on the `Endpoint number` so that the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of each record doesn't overlap.

This is a much simplified version of the actual script creating the view, but if you could show a simple way to achieve what I've explained here it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The 'earlier' record is determined _solely_ by the earliest start date?  What happens if there are 3 records with the same `endpoint_number`?

Comment: @X-Zero - Well I basically need to make sure the dates don't overlap

Comment: Oh, and if this is a view (Didn't quite catch that, intially), what is the original table definition/view script?  We may have _much_ better ways to solve this by referring to the base tables (and views-within-views is sometimes frowned upon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you've got a view V:

```
SELECT id, startdate, enddate, endpt
  FROM ...
```

You could modify this to something like:

```
SELECT id, startdate
     , CASE WHEN nextdt IS NULL THEN enddate ELSE nextdt - 1 END enddate, endpt
  FROM (SELECT id, startdate, enddate, endpt
             , LEAD(startdate) OVER (PARTITION BY endpt ORDER BY startdate) nextdt
          FROM  ...)
```

A simple example, using a table T instead of a view, with your data plus a third row, to illustrate the case identified by X-Zero's comment. It may not be what you want, so beware. The query will give you the enddate minus one for the *next* record.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (ID VARCHAR2(10), sd DATE, ed DATE, ep NUMBER);

Table created
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('G002S6YE',to_date('01/06/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'), to_date('31/05/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1012427316307);

1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('G002W1AY',to_date('27/06/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'), to_date('30/09/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1012427316307);

1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('G002W1AX',to_date('29/06/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'), to_date('30/06/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), 1012427316307);

1 row inserted

SQL> SELECT id, sd
  2       , CASE WHEN nextdt IS NULL THEN ed ELSE nextdt - 1 END ed, ep
  3    FROM (SELECT id, sd, ed, ep
  4               , LEAD(sd) OVER (PARTITION BY ep ORDER BY sd) nextdt
  5            FROM  t);

ID         SD          ED                  EP
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------
G002S6YE   1/6/2011    26/6/2011   1012427316
G002W1AY   27/6/2011   28/6/2011   1012427316
G002W1AX   29/6/2011   30/6/2012   1012427316
```